# Windows 8, repeatedly plays a audio ad every 5 - 10 minutes

Tags: windows-8

Since yesterday I keep having part of an audio ad playing on my Windows 8 HP laptop every 5-10 minutes. I was downloading music and films at the time, I can't seem to get rid of it?

Comment: open up the mixer. You have per-application volume controls, which should show you what app's doing it

Comment: were is the mixer ?

Comment: Right click on the speaker symbol on the taskbar.

Comment: I have 2 internet explorer icons in there do I turn them down ?

Comment: What other icons are there? What's opened in the Internet Explorer? Could you check whether the audio plays again after closing IE instances?

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your machine, if it persists after a reboot, check what start up programs you have under Task Manager. If there's nothing out of the ordinary in there, you've likely got a virus.

Run a full scan with up to date AV software and hopefully it's nothing too serious.

Comment: how do I do a system reboot ?

Comment: Reboot = restart. At this point I would advise to educate more on safe browsing, using NoScript / Adblock stuff and having a proper anti-virus in place along with anti-exploit such as EMET. A long way to go definitely, but worth a shot in the long run